# Change Azure Service Bus Namespace name

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

I am using Azure service bus namespace name **testnamespace.servicebus.windows.net** with premium tier.
Can I change namespace name **testnamespace**.servicebus.windows.net to **changenamespace**.servicebus.windows.net ?

Please suggest way for same.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. You have to create a new namespace with your new name.